# gdx-bullet hello world first use

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to use gdx-bullet stand alone and run the hello world like in the cpp one and I am getting values from 0 to 2 and up.

Why is that in the jbullet and cpp bullet is working fine
any idea why is it maybe is the `setToTranslation` or the string output 
[image](https://ibb.co/88nmMs0).
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Bullet.init();

  btCollisionConfiguration collisionConfig;
  btCollisionDispatcher dispatcher;
  btBroadphaseInterface overlappingPairCache;
  btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver solver;
  btDiscreteDynamicsWorld dynamicWorld;
  ArrayList<btCollisionShape> collisionShapes;

  collisionShapes = new ArrayList<btCollisionShape>();
  collisionConfig = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
  dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfig);
  overlappingPairCache = new btDbvtBroadphase();
  solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
  dynamicWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, overlappingPairCache, solver, collisionConfig);

  dynamicWorld.setGravity(new Vector3(0, -10f, 0));
  {
     btCollisionShape groundShape = new btBoxShape(new Vector3(50.f, 50.f, 50.f));
     collisionShapes.add(groundShape);

     Matrix4 groundTransform = new Matrix4();
     groundTransform.setToTranslation(new Vector3(0, -56, 0));

     float mass = 0f;
     boolean isDynamic = (mass != 0f);
     Vector3 localInertia = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
     if (isDynamic)
        groundShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass, localInertia);

     btDefaultMotionState myMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(groundTransform);
     btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo = new btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(mass, myMotionState, groundShape,
           localInertia);
     btRigidBody body = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);
     dynamicWorld.addRigidBody(body);
  }

  {
     btCollisionShape colShape = new btSphereShape(1.f);
     collisionShapes.add(colShape);

     Matrix4 startTransform = new Matrix4();
     startTransform.setToTranslation(new Vector3(2, 10, 0));

     float mass = 1;
     boolean isDynamic = (mass != 0f);
     Vector3 localInertia = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
     if (isDynamic)
        colShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass, localInertia);

     btDefaultMotionState myMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(startTransform);
     btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbInfo = new btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(mass, myMotionState, colShape,
           localInertia);
     btRigidBody body = new btRigidBody(rbInfo);
     dynamicWorld.addRigidBody(body);
  }


  for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
     dynamicWorld.stepSimulation(1.f / 60.f, 10);
     for (int j = dynamicWorld.getNumCollisionObjects() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        btCollisionObject obj = dynamicWorld.getCollisionObjectArray().atConst(j);
        btRigidBody body = (btRigidBody) obj;
        if (body != null && body.getMotionState() != null) {
           Matrix4 trans = new Matrix4();
           body.getMotionState().getWorldTransform(trans);
           System.out.println(
                 "world pos " + j + " = " + trans.val[12] + " , " + trans.val[13] + ", " + trans.val[14]);
        }
     }
  }

  collisionShapes.clear();
  dynamicWorld.dispose();
  overlappingPairCache.dispose();
  dispatcher.dispose();
  collisionConfig.dispose();

}
```

How does the second character feel about the protagonist?

Something the protagonist would like to say to the second character

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble understanding the problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It'll be helpful to understand the scene you have and what process you wish to perform on the object using Bullet. Regarding setToTranslation(), remember that this function resets your transformation matrix and sets its translation components to the new given values

Comment: in the image you can see in the console log it get from 0.0 to 2.275 that is not a normal behavior  i am trying to do the hello word bullet to see if i get the same result like in the cpp

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you're printing the "world pos" which I assume you want to print the world position of trans. If so, in the transformation matrix, the translation components are x=[0,3], y=[1,3], z=[2,3] (which you can relate as the position of the object in your 3D world)